# tableview displaying multiplication table of the number entered in textview of customviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multiplication

Iam a newbiee i so much browsed and managed to go so far.
What i want is to have a UITableView with first cell a CustomViewcell with a TEXTVIEW.
On entering a number in the TextView. 
below cells have to display the multiplication table of that entered number.

My code is as follows

```
     #import "ViewController.h"
     @interface ViewController ()

     @end

     @implementation ViewController
     @synthesize myTable,myArray,searchStr;;
     - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
         [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
         self.myArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"x 1 = ",@"x 2 = ",@"x 3 = ",@"x 4 =          ",@"x 5 = ",@"x 6 = " ,@"x 7 = ",@"x 8 = ",@"x 9 = ",@"x 10 =",nil];
     }

     - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
     {
         [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }
     -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsinTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
              {
         return 1;
     }


     -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:         (NSInteger)section
     {
         return 11;
     }

     -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:         (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         if (cell == nil)
         {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
             ////you another code..
         }
         if(indexPath.row<12)
         {
             if(indexPath.row>0)
             {
             cell.textLabel.text=[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];

             }
         }
         else
         {
             UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,          0.0f, 300.0f, 100.0f)];
             [[cell contentView] addSubview:textView];

         }
             return cell;

     }
     @end
```

pls help me 
im totaly stuck
no idea how to get number from textview and display it in the below cells
like

No.  * 1 = answr

like when entertd 5 in text view must display

5 * 1 = 5
5 * 2 = 10 so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
         cell.textLabel.text=[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
```

With this:

```
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %d",number,self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1,number*indexPath.row];
```

where number = [textView.text intValue];

But to get the number from textview,its not automatic, but there's lot of ways.  But since you are newbie, i would suggest you use a button, which on click saves the number = [textview.text intValue] and reloads the table.

Comment: nice iam trying this
before tht why doesnt the keyboard go down after i type the text it keeps staying in the screen

Comment: to make the keyboard resign you need to call the resignFirstResponder. In the implementation of the button add this line. [textView resignFirstResponder]; By this way when you click the button, your keyboard will resign.

Comment: you need to declare the textView globally to use it in the buttons implementation

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the point to look at in order to achieve what you want.
First have a look at `UITExtFieldDelegate` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing:)

This is where you will be able to get the user input. In particular `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` could be sued to validate user input.

Once you have the user input, you can fill you array `myArray` and call `[self reloadData]` to refresh the tableView.

Hope it helps

Comment: But why do i need an array

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend simply having the `UITableView`'s data source be derived from a separate `UITextField` value.  What is the value in creating a custom cell for this?  Your UITableViewDataSource implementation will have odd bounds checks in it.

The first cell of the table ultimately can and will be re-used when it scrolls off the screen, so you are still ultimately relying on a backing `NSString *myString`

Comment: i am totaly new to objective c and ios i am not sure wht ur answer is could u make it simple or give me an example